# How to remove first semicolon in insert

Tags: apex

Below is the method when triggered it is inserting multiselected records delimited by semicolon. When inserting, initially a semicolon is getting inserted like below pic. How can I remove the first semicolon?

```
public PageReference save()
   {
      Id rfpId;
      rfpId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rfpId');
      //upsert accounts;
       List<ChildRFP__c> rfpchild = new List<ChildRFP__c>();


       for(integer i=0;i< attendeeList1.size(); i++){
            if(attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule.size()!=0){
           for(integer j=0; j<attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule.size(); j++ ){
                s = s + '; ' + attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule[j];
           }
           rfpchild.add(new ChildRFP__c(Name = 'TestNow2', Custom_Package__c = s,Market__c =attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule1));
           s=' ';

           }
       }
            if (rfpchild.size() > 0 ) {
                insert rfpchild;
            }



       return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rfpId'));    
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify this line as follows

```
    List<String> setStr = new List<String>();
    for(integer j=0; j<attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule.size(); j++ ){
            setStr.add(attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule[j]);
       }

    s = String.join(setStr,';');
```

Comment: Thnnx Himanshu....This worked....

Comment: fantastic!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_removeStart

The removeStart method can do this.  After your loop:

```
s = s.removeStart(';');
```

Comment: AFter which loop should i use the line..

Comment: Right before rfpchild.add(new ChildRFP__c(Name = 'TestNow2', Custom_Package__c = s,Market__c =attendeeList1[i].discountSchedule1));
           s=' ';

Comment: No..The semicolon is still there...

Comment: It shouldn't be unless you have something else prepended to it.  I just ran the code in my org and it worked exactly as I expected.

Comment: Ok.. Let me chk once again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.join as below

```
List<Integer> li = new    List<Integer> {10, 20, 30};
String s = String.join(li, '/');
System.assertEquals('10/20/30', s);
```